# Parkingcrew.net hijacking our domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hijack

We are experiencing a very bizarre sort of hijack on our domain www.lbps.co.uk .

It seems to render fine on desktop systems and on mobile devices over WIFI it also seems fine.

However when WIFI is disabled on the mobile devices the site instead redirects to a parkingcrew.net spam link page displaying mortgage info links. This bizarrely at present seems restricted to the UK.

After spending 4 days and sleepless nights over this (I'm not a huge tech expert) with our developers we are thinking that possibly there is a DNS issue or virus?

If anyone can help it would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Someone probably injected malicious code into your CMS/scripts. If you give us the actual domain name we can probably offer more info.

Comment: From a quick look I didn't see any malicious scripts. You may have had the DNS hijacked on your local network.

Comment: Hi there - the domain is lbps.co.uk - Is it possible the DNS can be hijacked just for a cellular network? I've never seen anything like this in my life

Comment: Might it be an IPv4 vs IPv6 name resolution difference?

Comment: Thanks Ryan - how is this tested / resolved?

Comment: You would need a client that has a working IPv6 WAN connection.  Then you could issue a DNS lookup for the AAAA record (the IPv6 equivalent of a DNS A record) on your site.